# Accessing memory at 0xF000FFFE (computer type) in fasm (MS-DOS)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, fasm, real-mode

The problem is: I need to get 'computer' type from BIOS memory. I know, that I can do it that way in fasm (my program and all segments are 16 bits):

```
mov al, [0xF000FFFE]
```

but that returnes zero and it is not right, because equivalent code in turbo c++ 3.1

```
UCHAR pcType = *((UCHAR*)0xF000FFFE);
```

returnes right 'type' of my computer, **when using LARGE model** (in code generation settings).
So how to fix it in fasm ? (for example I know, that masm has .model directive, but there is no such thing in fasm). Please, help...

Comment: No... tried. And I also get zero for some other addresses, while in c++ it is alright...

Comment: As far as I understood, first I should enter unreal mode, so my call should look like that:
 

    mov ax, 0xF000 
    mov ds, ax 
    mov al, [0xFFFE]

That works nicely))

Answer (score 2):

Turbo-C is performing instructions to read from the **far** address 0xF000FFFE. The segment is the upper 16-bits of the address and the offset is the lower 16-bit of the address. In large memory model the **far** pointer 0xF000FFFE points to segment 0xF000, offset = 0xFFFE. A real-mode [segment:offset (logical) address](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) is translated to a physical address by the calculation `(segment<<4)+offset`, which in this case is physical address (0xF000<<4)+0xFFFE = 0xFFFFE which is the second last byte below the 1MiB mark of memory within the ROM BIOS where the system ID byte resides.

You will need to create equivalent FASM code to set one of the segment registers to 0xF000 and then retrieve the value at the offset 0xFFFE. The following code simply returns the system ID back to DOS via the error level (code) returned by [Int 21h/AH=4Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm). The return value is in *AL*:

```
format mz                      ; Create a DOS EXE program

    mov ax, 0xf000
    mov es, ax                 ; ES = 0xf000
    mov al, [es:0xfffe]        ; Read byte at 0xF000:0xFFFE

    mov ah, 4Ch                ; DOS Exit and Return with error code function
    int 21h                    ; Exit and return System ID in AL
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in Turbo C because it interprets the 32-bit value as a segment:offset pair and not as a flat pointer. If you want to use the flat pointer, you should use the address 0xFFFFFFFE (if flash memory mapping has not been disabled by the BIOS), or 0xFFFFE which is the linear memory address corresponding to the pointer F000:FFFE. Both of these work only in unreal mode since they use offsets greater than 64K, which is not possible in plain real mode. The easiest is probably to use plain 16-bit segment:offset addressing like you mention in your comment, since that will always work.